# How to check if user is still present?

Tags: c#, asp.net, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check connection is active in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761376/check-connection-is-active-in-asp-net)

Is there a way in ASP.NET to check if the browser where the page was requested is still open? If the browser is closed, a way to stop the request's rendering.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761376/check-connection-is-active-in-asp-net

Comment: Depending on your requirement, creating a simple JavaScript AJAX ping that calls home every few seconds while the browser is open might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Response.IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx)